# This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 4.0 or newer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I opened my project in Android Studio `canary 4`, then I decided to open it in `stable version 3.5.1`
Now I get the following message.

> This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry
>   with Android Studio 4.0 or newer.

I tried followings

1. deleting `.gradle`, `.idea`, `gradle/`, `project.iml`
2. invalidate cache
3. close and reimport project
4. changed the `agp` and `Kotlin` to previous versions.

Seems I have to stick with 4.0.

Comment: Look in the `build.gradle` in your project root directory. What do you have for the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version number?

Comment: @CommonsWare I already did it, I updated the question.

Comment: @user158 *What do you have for the com.android.tools.build:gradle version number?*

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it's `3.5.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I was able to fixed the issue, what had happened

I was using `buildSrc` to declare my dependencies, I had changed the `AGP` and `Kotlin` versions in `buildSrc`, but when opening the project with AS canary, AS have added an extra `AGP` dependency statement in addition to the existing `AGP` dependency statement referring `buildSrc`

ex:

```
dependencies {
    classpath GradlePlugins.GRADLE
    ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha06'
}
```

Removing additionally added `AGP` dependency fixed the issue.

---

Other than that remove the following line from `repositories` blocks in project `build.gradle`, since it is for a bug fix in AS Canary 4.0

```
// maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
```

Answer (score 15):

I just had this issue. To fix it I only needed to change in my build.gradle from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

The latest non 4.x version of the gradle plug-in
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Then, after a gradle sync, everything worked properly. I didn't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting `~./android/build-cache/4.x` and `~./android/build-cache/4.x.lock`

After removing the file and directory above, re-start the project and check if those show up again under `build-cache`. If they show up that means `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.x` is still applied somewhere in your project. I searched the file from Finder and Android Studio that had `4.x` name on it and changed it to `3.5.2`

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I switched to `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3"` then `Clean` & `Build`

Answer (score 0):

Update Gradle in Android Studio to the latest version.